How to Dynamically Link Agent Properties to Select Output in AnyLogic?
I'm working on a simulation in AnyLogic where I need to dynamically link a property of each agent to a Select Output block. The goal is for the property to vary for each agent as they enter the Select Output, influencing which path they take based on its value at that moment. I tried setting the property within the agent's initialization and again just before the Select Output, using code like agent.property = uniform(0, 5);, but it seems the changes are not being consistently applied by the time they reach the Select Output.
Has anyone encountered this issue or could provide guidance on ensuring the property is correctly updated and used in the Select Output decision-making?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Does this answer your question? Unexpected behavior SelectOutput block in AnyLogic
